# why is nested for loop not capturing all values from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, nested, dataset

[image]from Allan Visochek's book, practical data wrangling, chp 3,
using python 3, conda 6.0.1

```
new_scf_data=[]

variables= ["address", "created_at","description","lng","lat","rating"]

for old_entry in scf_data["issues"]:
    new_entry={}
    for variable in variables:
        new_entry[variable] = old_entry[variable]
new_scf_data.append(new_entry)
print(new_entry)
{   'address': '2501 Granada Circle West Saint Petersburg, Florida',
    'created_at': '2017-08-26T16:19:53-04:00',
    'description': 'Grass has not been cut in over 3 weeks.',
    'lat': 27.7325689,
    'lng': -82.6684505,
    'rating': 1}
```

This code should return a nested dictionary with several keys, with their values. However, after running the code, only one "case" of the original dataset. Please keep in mind that im a total noob.

Please advise

much appreciated

Comment: The expected output is around 900 lines of code vs the 7ish im getting. The one that I got (displayed in the original comment) is just 1 case of the nested dictionary. Im supposed to get around much more than just 1 "case". Each case, has the keys in variables for all nested dict.

Comment: Please [edit] it into the question and format it as code.

Comment: You still haven't made it clear what you're going for, but I think you want to add `new_entry` to a list inside the loop, then print out the list. You're never saving `new_entry` anywhere.

Comment: It looks like you intended to add them to a list at some point. You have a `new_scf_data` list at the top that you never use.

Comment: correct, but after retracing that step, i found out that the for loop doesnt cover the rest of the nested dict in scf_data. Instead, it chooses a random dict and returns it..

Comment: Is the indentation of the line `new_scf_data.append(new_entry)` correct? Because it is outside of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the cause. Apparently, Jupyter wasnt running certain lines of code. After further investigation, turns out that the updated version of Tornado was to blame. I downgraded the same, and now im able to run the code w/o any problems.

https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/401

cheers to all!